# C# Mouse Move and Click relative to active window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent

Hi I have been using code similar to this in a piece of automation I have been working on

```
public static void LeftClick(int x, int y)
{
    Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); //<= fails without this
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

However unless I am being dumb this move the mouse to the x,y from the top left of the screen which causes me problems if the active window isn't where Im expecting it to be, can anyone suggest a way of achieving the same functionality with moving the mouse to a point relative to the active window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pinvoke GetWindowRect() to find out where the window is located.  So you can adjust *x* and *y* by the window position.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Comment: Hi there thanks for that it seems GetWindowRect is what I need I have visited pinvoke.net I am just confused as to how to get the window handle could someone give me a pointer.

Comment: Lots of questions here about that.  Search for EnumWindows, FindWindow, GetClassName, Spy++.

Comment: Ive used ui spy on the java app in question and the window comes back as SunAwtDialog but GetWindowRect(SunAwtDialog.hWnd, rct); isnt right

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the location (relative to the screen) of the window you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is indeed the expected behavior. The [`Cursor.Position` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) describes the cursor's location in *screen* coordinates, not relative to your form.

However, every control exposes two handy methods that you can take advantage of to convert between screen coordinates and control coordinates:

- The [**`Control.PointToClient`** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) computes the location of the specified screen point into client coordinates. Use this to convert *from* screen coordinates *into* client coordinates (i.e., those relative to your control, such as a form).
- The [**`Control.PointToScreen`** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) computes the location of the specified client point into scren coordinates. Use this to convert *from* client coordinates *into* screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

try `PointToClient` and `PointToScreen` of the control you are trying to find relative points to.