# Is there a way to apply relative input in c#?

Tags: c#, mouse, rdp, hid

I'm working on a [project](https://github.com/BlackCharon142/RelativeMouseRDP) that's supposed to record relative mouse input on the client and send it to the host to get applied but I can't find any way to apply any data relatively in the host. every input move solution I found was absolute, meaning it's not relative

I've looked at
[c# How to simulate mouse INPUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926729/c-sharp-how-to-simulate-mouse-input)
and
[C# Mouse Move and Click relative to active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803996/c-sharp-mouse-move-and-click-relative-to-active-window) and [C# (CSharp) MOUSEINPUT Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/MOUSEINPUT/-/php-mouseinput-class-examples.html) and a lot of other low and top rated questions but either it wasn't the thing I was looking for or wasn't clear for me to understand

I tried to use some other solutions like using raw data and applying with HID([the kit I used](https://tetherscript.com/hid-driver-kit-home/)) but that didn't work either since it controls the mouse that is connected to the PC and not the one in the remote desktop

The closest answer I've found to this were [RemoteRelativeInput](https://github.com/TKMAX777/RemoteRelativeInput) project but it has been written in Go and I don't know how to work with that, and [relmouse_forward](https://github.com/am009/relmouse_forward) whose description is in Chinese and I can't understand Chinese(even with google translate), so basically if you can help me do the same thing I would really appreciate it

If anyone has any other solution to this problem, please explain it in detail since I'm not a professional

***Update***: I found these two structures but I'm not sure how can I get or push value with them
[INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) - [MOUSEINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-mouseinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking through GitHub for answers I found [InputSimulatorCore](https://github.com/cwevers/InputSimulatorCore)
It has a function called MoveMouseBy(deltaX,deltaY) which moves the cursor exactly like it's a real input and not an absolute value

if you don't know how to use the package, you need to install the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulatorCore/)
then add the using

`using WindowsInput;`

and whenever you want to simulate an input make a new instance of `InputSimulator` and choose the device and the move it should simulate

```
    InputSimulator inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
    inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(X, Y);
```